# Largest Contentful Paint - different scores?

Tags: wordpress

I have troubles with the Largest Contentful Paint on my Desktop-Sites. Since a few days the LCP is growing and growing and I don't know why and how I should stopp it. A problem is also that I get always different scores.

Page Speed Insights tells me that the featured image is the LCP and it takes 0,7 till 0,8 seconds for loading. The score for 28 days shows a value of 4,6s. That would be ok. But in search console under Web Core Vitals section I have 215 URLs for Desktop that have a LCP score of 7,4 seconds and it is getting higher and higher. When I do a test in WebDevTools in incognito mode the LCP for Desktop is about 9700 ms (too much). Why there is so a difference and what can I do to get the LCP down? The LCP wasn't a problem some days ago...

Greetings Kathrin

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the data you see in Chrome (Lighthouse) is so called Lab-data and does significantly differ from what you see in search console as search console uses field-data.

The field data is collected from all devices with a chrome installed accessing your website. So e.g. if your servers are in the US, but most of your users come from Africa, your LCP might be high as the image takes long time to load.

Another thing that could be a problem in your particular case is that as of some changes to your site, a different element became the LCP. This is something you can check in Lighthouse and see what element is the LCP, actually.